# Facebook Graph API - Getting facebook group posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to get posts from facebook groups using fb graph api ,php sdk. I can get posts from groups am admin but when i try to get posts from where am a member it returns an error

```
Graph returned an error: (#200) Requires either admin permissions or member using installed app.
```

here is the code

```
    try {               
       $postsdata= $fb->get('/6999406078/feed?limit=5&$accessToken='.APP_ID.'|'.APP_SECRET);
        $posts= $requestGroups->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
    $i =0;
    foreach ($posts as $key) {
        $i++;
        echo" Post number from $i". @$key['message'] . "<br>";
    }
```

How to fix this issue ? Is this possible to return posts from facebook groups am just member in ?

Comment: the error message tells you everything you need to know already. not sure what else to tell you, to be honest?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/group/feed#read is pretty clear and should not leave much room for (mis-)interpretation, no?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not possible to get feed from facebook groups without admin rights. It was possible a few months ago yet... but not now.

Comment: so this means that behalf the apis is not possible to access all the information that the web client (the facebook site) allows you?